# Why i cant use for this way?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

The plan is:

1. sort 'arr' from less to greater.
2. push values in range of both number from arr, inclusively.
3. find smallest common number which dividible on each value from 'arrForAll' without reminder.
4. Assign to 'i' first value from 'arrForAll'.
5. Output 'while' condition isn't false. Condition is: 'i' don't divide on each value from 'arrForAll' without reminder.

I tried this:

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  let sortedArray = arr.sort();
  let arrForAll = []
  for (let i = sortedArray[0]; i < sortedArray[1] + 1; i++) {
    arrForAll.push(i)
  }
  for (let i = sortedArray[1]; arrForAll.every(x => i % x !== 0); i += i) {
    console.log(i)
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(smallestCommons([1, 5]));
```

But console output nothing.
What's wrong in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conditioin of for loop it must use logic operators '<','>', etc.
So this situation while loop is more suitable solution

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
 var i=0;
 let sortedArray = arr.sort();//here store sorted value
 let arrForAll=[]
 for(let i=sortedArray[0];i<sortedArray[1]+1;i++){
 arrForAll.push(i)
 }//store [x to y]
 while(true){
 i+=sortedArray[1];
if(arrForAll.every(x => i % x == 0)){
break;
}
}
return i;}
console.log(smallestCommons([23, 18]));//returns 6056820, [1,5] will return 60
```